# A question about the minimal number of operations required to obtain a matrix with generic eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

Let $A,M \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that $M$ is invertible and $MA \neq AM$. Consider the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by the set $\{I,A,MAM^{-1}\}$, where $I$ denotes the identity. Does there always exist a matrix $T \in \mathcal{A}$ so that $T$ has distinct eigenvalues?

Context : the reason I am interested in this question is because I would like to see precisely how sensitive eigenvalues are with respect to performing really minimal matrix operations.

Comment: No. Replace $I_n,A$ and $M$ by $\pmatrix{I_n\\ &I_n},\pmatrix{A\\ &A}$ and $\pmatrix{M\\ &M}$. Then every matrix in the resulting algebra has a repeated eigenvalue.